# Multiple select query on sql

Tags: mysql

I have below table -

```
mysql> select * from appdata;
+------------+----------+-----------+
| timestamp  | appName  | Bytes     |
+------------+----------+-----------+
| 1454169299 | DNS      |    123456 |
| 1454169292 | DNS      |     12342 |
| 1454169292 | Facebook |   1234222 |
| 1454169297 | Youtube  | 123422233 |
+------------+----------+-----------+

I wanted to sum the byte and show the single application and consumed bytes
```

I executed

```
mysql> select appName,Sum(Bytes) from appdata group by appName;
+----------+------------+
| appName  | Sum(Bytes) |
+----------+------------+
| DNS      |     135798 |
| Facebook |    1234222 |
| Youtube  |  123422233 |
+----------+------------+
```

now I want to run a single query which gives me the app which has consumed more bytes

```
youtube  123422233
Facebook 1234222
DNS 135798
```

I am running

```
select appName,Sum(Bytes) from appdata group by appName
    (select appName,Bytes FROM appdata ORDER BY Bytes desc limit 3);
```

But its not working, Please let me know how can i achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT appname, SUM(bytes) FROM appdata GROUP BY appname ORDER BY SUM(bytes) DESC LIMIT 3;`

You need to order by the sum of Bytes descending, this way you'll get the highest numbers first.